# Is it possible to change z-Index of the draggable elements when mousedown?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, draggable

I found that the `stack option` of `JQuery UI draggable` was very useful , but it only work when I dragging the elements .So, can I change the `stack value` of elements which draggable just when I `**click the elements**` or **`with the mousedown event`** ??

Thank you very much~~!!

**The way the draggable plugin to change draggable elements stack[z-index] order is dragging and moving the element.If you only click the draggable element it doesn't change the stack order.And I want it to change when I click.**

Comment: I could not understand you, what do you want to mean with stack value?

Comment: You means z-index value?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. You mean, you don't want to drag them *at all*, you just want clicking them to change their stacking order. If that's right, then ignore my answer, it won't help.

Comment: T.J.Crowder.You mean dragging and moving is the only way the change the stack order of draggable elements??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this not working for you?

```
$(element).mousedown(function(){
    ...
})
```

Comment: The question is what to put inside the function, if my (revised) understanding of the question (see my comment up top) is correct...

Comment: I just want to change the stack order of the elements when I click them

Answer (score 0):

**Note** See my comment on your question, I think both times I was writing the below I misunderstood it.

---

If you're looking to ensure that the item you're dragging is always above everything else during the drag, you can set the `z-index` <s>in a selector matching your draggable with the class `ui-draggable-dragging`. jQuery UI adds that class to the element being dragged during the drag operation.</s>

So for instance, let's say you're dragging spans that are inside a div called `foo`. The CSS would be:

```
#foo span.ui-draggable-dragging {
    z-index: 1000 !important;   /* Sadly, you may need the !important */
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ajeha3)

Since the class is only added during the drag, that `z-index` value will only take effect during the drag. See the "overview" in [the docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/).

**Edit**: ...by using [the `zIndex` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-zIndex) ([live example](http://jsbin.com/ajeha3/2)).

Answer (score 0):

You might place the following code after the draggable plugin ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AHz6x/1/)):

```
(function ($) {
    var _create =  $.ui.draggable.prototype._create;

    $.ui.draggable.prototype._create = function () {
        var self = this;

        self.element.mousedown(function (e) {
            self._mouseStart(e);
            self._trigger('start', e);
            self._clear();
        });

        _create.call(self);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Or, you might want to make it into a separate option as follows ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EdxX8/)):

```
(function ($) {
    $.ui.plugin.add('draggable', 'increaseZindexOnmousedown', {
        create: function () {
            this.mousedown(function (e) {
                var inst = $(this).data('draggable');
                inst._mouseStart(e);
                inst._trigger('start', e);
                inst._clear();
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Rather than posting the exact same answer multiple times, you should flag the question as duplicate of the other one you replied to if they are indeed the same.

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community.

Answer (score 0):

Since I found this question when I was searching, I figured I would post the answer I found.  The reason a click does not change the z-index is that the drag hasn't initiated yet.  To force the drag to be initiated on all clicks, set the distance option to 0:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable#option-distance

The behavior is nearly the same as the default, except now z-order changes even with no mouse motion.